# RapidMiner TimeStamp preprocessing

Tags: timestamp, preprocessor, weka, rapidminer

I am trying to make predictions with three different sensor data. Each sensor has a periodicity, and measurement instants are not the same (e.g. sensor1data_time=10:01; sensor2data_timestamp= 10:03; sensor3data_timestamp= 10:05).

I did this task manually for a demo, but now I need to do automatize it in order to develop a prediction model.

Any preprocessing task recommended??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would round the times to something like the nearest ten minutes. The operator to use is `Generate Attributes`. I tend to use the number of seconds since 01-01-1970. The following fragments show the functions you could use. I'm assuming you have an attribute called datestr containing a date in this sort of format 13-01-2016 23:01:01.

```
attribute name    function expression    
-------------------------------------------------------------------
date              date_parse_custom(datestr, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
epochdate         date_diff(date_parse(0), date)/1000
dateToTenMins     600*round(epochdate/600)
```

The epoch date is in milliseconds so dividing by 1000 gives seconds.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for your help. However, in case more than one value rounds to the same timestamp, could I use `FilterExamples ` operator to delete duplicate values??

Comment: You could use the `Aggregate` operator to count the number of examples with the same timestamp. You would expect to see 1 for each timestamp from each sensor.

Comment: Really helpful your advice :) Just one more question. I don't get it why you are using the `600`. I mean, if instead of rounding to the nearest five minutes, in case I wanted to round to the lower hour?? For example, if for 1:03 and 1:53 I want to get 1:00 for both of them?? How could I do this??

Comment: My mistake - 600 is to the nearest 10 minutes. You would use 300 for 5 minutes and 3600 for the nearest hour. I'll edit the answer so it stands alone better.

Comment: Yeah, finally I was able to figure it out. You provide me exactly with what I needed to solve my problem. Thanks!! :)